# Android: How can I create a RecyclerView where I can freely drag and drop an item to do certain things?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I am facing a tricky task where I have a horizontal RecyclerView where the user should be able to grab the first item and freely move it. If he drops it in two certain areas, it will be added into the other two lists respectively.

Here is a diagram for the explicit task:

[image]

Basically the user can only grab the first item and then choose to drop it inside favourite list or add it in the disliked list. The move should be 100% free and follow the user's finger on the screen. If the item gets dropped halfway between the original middle list and one of the top or bottom list, but closer to the result list, the item should then have a smooth animation towards the other list with some sort of interpolation [This is an important part, the animation should be very smooth to the point that the card gets on the final position].

I have never done anything like it, only have a little experience with MotionLayout but I know that's not of use in this example. At first glance, I expect that this can be done with DragEvents but I have no idea where to start. Any help or examples to teach me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please take a look on https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

Fast and versatile Adapter for RecyclerView which regroups several features into one library to considerably improve the user experience